# Notepad++ RegEx on XML File

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

First, I am new to regular expressions.

I have an XML File that is formatted as so:

```
<SCHED_TABLE LAST_UPLOAD="" ... TABLE_NAME="">
<JOB
  APPLICATION=""
  ...
  NODEID="foo"
  ...
>
</JOB>
<JOB
  APPLICATION=""
  ...
  NODEID="bar"
  ...
>
</JOB>
</SCHED_TABLE>
```

With a whole lot of lines in between.  What I need to do is write a regular expression to find all the JOB's where NODEID != foo.  Those that do NOT equal foo will be replaced with a blank, therefore deleting those jobs.  The whole job needs to be deleted including the open and close JOB tag.

Any advice for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (untested):

Find:

```
<JOB[^>]+?NODEID="(?!foo)[^>]+?>.+?</JOB>
```

Replace with blank.

Make sure `. matches newline` (or whatever that option is called -- I'm away from my normal computer) is checked.

Breakdown of how this works:

- `<JOB` matches the start of a JOB tag.
- `[^>]+?` matches everything that is not a `>` symbol, but the `?` means "don't be greedy" -- that is, don't use more characters than you need to.
- `NODEID="` means match literally those characters.
- `(?!foo)` is a negative look-ahead pattern.  It means, "This is not a match if everything has worked so far but the text following this point is `foo`."
- `[^>]+?`, again, all non-`>` characters, but not greedy.
- `>` match the `>` character exactly.
- `.+?` Match any string of characters, but don't be greedy (i.e., stop when you hit the last part of the regex, `</JOB>`)
- `</JOB>` closing tag.

Ordinarily, `.+?` would not match newline characters, which is why you need to tell Notepad++ to let it do so.

Comment: Ed, if you don't mind, can you take a moment and explain each step of this expression in regular terms?  I want to make sure I understand exactly what is going on.  Again, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Glad it helped. I added an explanation above.